# How to explain that there are 9 times of destruction?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to learn what differences are between `push_back()` and `emplace_back()`, especially when the elements are class type.So I write code like following:

```
int cnt = 0;
class foo{
public:
    //constructor
    foo() : ucnt(++cnt) { cout << ucnt << "\tdefault" << endl; }
    foo(const foo&) : ucnt(++cnt) { cout << ucnt << "\tcopy" << endl; }
    ~foo() { cout << ucnt << "\tdestroyed" << endl; }
    int ucnt;
};

int main()
{
    vector<foo> vf = {foo()};
    cout << vf.size() << " : " << vf[0].ucnt << endl;
    vf.push_back(foo());
    cout << vf.size() << " : " << vf[0].ucnt << " " << vf[1].ucnt << endl;
    vf.emplace_back(foo());
    cout << vf.size() << " : " << vf[0].ucnt << " " << vf[1].ucnt << " " << vf[2].ucnt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

whose result is:

```
1       default
2       copy
1       destroyed
1 : 2
3       default
4       copy
5       copy
2       destroyed
3       destroyed
2 : 5 4
6       default
7       copy
8       copy
9       copy
5       destroyed
4       destroyed
6       destroyed
3 : 8 9 7
8       destroyed
9       destroyed
7       destroyed
```

It seems like all the elements in `vf` are copyed and then destroyed while executing `push_back()` and `emplace_back()`.Why?

Comment: Because you have a copy constructor the default move constructor will not be generated/used.  Try adding it as default.

Comment: you should not put the temp object to emplace... it will call default constructor for you, saving you one additional move - vf.emplace_back(foo()); should be vf.emplace_back();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### emplace_back

The advantage of emplace_back is that it passes its arguments directly to the constructor of the to-be-emplaced class and constructs the new object in place instead of copy constructing it.

e.g.

```
elections.emplace_back("Nelson Mandela", "South Africa", 1994);
```

As opposed to push_back, where you pass a temporary object and copy construct the new object.
e.g.

```
elections.push_back(President("Franklin Delano Roosevelt", "the USA", 1936));
```

so in your case it should be

```
vf.emplace_back();
```

since you have no ctor arguments to be passed to the in place constructor. Compared to

```
vf.push_back(foo());
```

#### Constructor balance

The many unexpected copies and deletes stem from resizing the vector.

**up to 1. cout**

1 temporary created, and destroyed in constructor
= 1x default, 1x copy, 1x destroyed ✔️

**up to 2. cout**

1 temporary created and destroyed in push_back
1 existing object copied to the resized vector, therefor copy-created and destroyed
= 1x default, 2x copy, 2x destroyed ✔️

**up to 3. cout**

1 temporary created and destroyed in emplace_back
2 existing objects copied to the resized vector, therefor copy-created and destroyed
= 1x default, 3x copy, 3x destroyed ✔️

and so on

#### Edit: Example

The following code is from **Artemy Vysotsky**, see comment under this answer and shows exactly to the point how it is done right. Especially note the use of `.reserve(3)` to avoid reallocation orgies.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int cnt = 0;
class foo{
public:
    //constructor
    foo() : ucnt(++cnt) { cout << ucnt << "\tdefault\n" ; }
    foo(const foo&) : ucnt(++cnt) { cout << ucnt << "\tcopy\n" ; }
    foo(foo&&) noexcept : ucnt(++cnt) { cout << ucnt << "\tmove\n" ; }
    ~foo() { cout << ucnt << "\tdestroyed\n" ; }
    int ucnt;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> vf = {foo()};
    cout << vf.size() << " 1: " << vf[0].ucnt << '\n';
    vf.reserve(3);
    cout << vf.size() << " 2: " << vf[0].ucnt << '\n';
    vf.push_back(foo());
    cout << vf.size() << " 3: " << vf[0].ucnt << " " << vf[1].ucnt << '\n';
    vf.emplace_back();
    cout << vf.size() << " 4: " << vf[0].ucnt << " " << vf[1].ucnt << " " << vf[2].ucnt << '\n';
    return 0;
}
/***************
 Output
 $ ./test
 1       default
 2       copy
 1       destroyed
 1 1: 2
 3       move
 2       destroyed
 1 2: 3
 4       default
 5       move
 4       destroyed
 2 3: 3 5
 6       default
 3 4: 3 5 6
 3       destroyed
 5       destroyed
 6       destroyed
 *****************/
```

Comment: I have added sample that shows that by using reserve additional copy constructors could be avoided. And it is easy to see difference between push_back and emplace_back - https://gist.github.com/artemyv/6d07927980bf8d8f2536354cc8bc5c98

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Yes. That is exactly how it should be done!

Comment: I forgot - that marking the move constructor noexcept we can switch from copy to move when reserve is called - gist is updated