# Why vector hold a class type will call the copy constructor one more time when push_back()?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor, push-back

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class Quote {
public:
    Quote() = default;
    Quote(const std::string &book, double sales_price):
                     bookNo(book), price(sales_price) {  }
    // Quote(const Quote&) = default;  // memberwise copy
    Quote(const Quote &orig): bookNo(orig.bookNo), price(orig.price) {
        cout << orig.isbn() << endl;
        cout << "called Quote(const Quote &)" << endl;
    }
    Quote& operator=(const Quote&) = default;   // copy assign

    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    virtual double net_price(std::size_t n) const
                { cout << "Quote::net_price\n"; return n * price; }
    virtual void debug() const { cout << bookNo << ' ' << price << endl; }
    virtual ~Quote() = default;
private:
    std::string bookNo; // ISBN number of this item
protected:
    double price = 0.0; // normal, undiscouted price
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<Quote> basket;
    basket.push_back(Quote("0-201-82470-1", 50));
    basket.push_back(Quote("0-201-82XXXXX", 30));
    cout << "\ntraverse bakset" << endl;
    for (const auto &v : basket)
        v.debug();
}
```

After I compile the above code and run, the result is:

```
0-201-82470-1
called Quote(const Quote &)
0-201-82XXXXX
called Quote(const Quote &)
0-201-82470-1
called Quote(const Quote &)

traverse bakset
0-201-82470-1 50
0-201-82XXXXX 30
```

According to when copy constructor is called, it will *be called twice* because I just have pushed two elements when I `push_back()` to a vector. But why it is *called three times* displayed in the above result.
However, according to the for-loop in `main`, the element of the vector is right.

Why the copy constructor is called one more time when pushed to a vector? And is there anything wrong with my defined copy constructor?

Comment: What happens when the vector runs out of space?

Comment: @tkausl, sorry. I have not encountered the case that the vector runs out of space.

Comment: @tkausl. Thanks. I may have understood your meaning.

Comment: @zhenguoli you could also provide move semantics to potentially avoid some copying if you really want to.

Comment: @WhozCraig. Yes. I have tested move constructor also. But I have found the problem, so I removed the move constructor. Thank you.

Comment: @zhenguoli Wasn't saying it was a problem, I was simply pointing out that if you can provide move semantics it is generally always preferred to copy semantics. You can, of course, provide both and let the container sort it out. For example, in your original code providing move semantics and using container emplacement would eliminate *all* copies. Anyway, glad you found something that works for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig. Thank you. I understand. The problem I said I found is the problem I described in the question. So I removed the move semantics to make the question I asked clear. It does not refer to the problem caused by the move semantics. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is called at the 2nd time, reallocation happened. (More precisely it happens when the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()`.) Then the old underlying storage of the `vector` will be destroyed and the new one will be allocated, and elements need to be copied to the new storage, which cause the copy constructor to be called.

You can use [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid reallocation. e.g.

```
vector<Quote> basket;
basket.reserve(2);
basket.push_back(Quote("0-201-82470-1", 50));
basket.push_back(Quote("0-201-82XXXXX", 30)); // no reallocation here
```

Comment: you can use emplace_back to avoid copy constructor at all `basket.emplace_back("0-201-82470-1", 50);`

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky That will not avoid copies when a vector reallocation happens. The correct way to avoid that copy is to implement a move constructor (which the compiler can do automatically, but won't here because of the user-defined copy constructor and copy assignment operator).

Comment: I mean use emplace_back in addition to reserve. move constructor has to be noexcept to be used by vector when resizing. Demo that shows the difference between push_back and emplace could be seen here https://gist.github.com/artemyv/6d07927980bf8d8f2536354cc8bc5c98 - it was answer ro similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893180/how-to-explain-that-there-are-9-times-of-destruction

Answer (score 0):

As per [C++ language open standard draft n3690.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) 
regarding vector capacity. Please see the bold italicized statement.

> 23.3.7.3 vector capacity [vector.capacity]
>   size_type capacity() const noexcept;
>   1 Returns: The total number of elements that the vector can hold without requiring reallocation.
>   void reserve(size_type n);
>   2 Requires: T shall be MoveInsertable into *this.
>   3 Effects: A directive that informs a vector of a planned change in size, so that it can manage the storage
>   allocation accordingly. After reserve(), capacity() is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if
>   reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of capacity() otherwise. "***Reallocation happens
>   at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of reserve()***". If an exception
>   is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-CopyInsertable type, there are no effects

Also from Scott Meyers "**Effective C++ Digital Collection: 140 Ways to Improve Your Programming**", under item 14
Item 14.

> Use reserve to avoid unnecessary reallocations.
>   One of the most marvelous things about STL containers is that they automatically grow to accommodate as much data as you put into them, provided only that you don't exceed their maximum size. (To discover this maximum, just call the aptly named max_size member function.) For vector and string, growth is handled by doing the moral equivalent of a realloc whenever more space is needed. This realloc-like operation has four parts:
>   1. Allocate a new block of memory that is some multiple of the container's current capacity. 
>   **In most implementations, vector and string capacities grow by a factor of between 1.5 and 2 each time**.

As suggested by "**songyuanyao**" one should reserve the size(if it is known in advance) to avoid frequent reallocation.